# How to convert every second element of an array into hash value

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
string = "a@b@c@d@e@f@g@h@...@z"
```

I want:

```
{:a => "b", :c => "d", :e => "f", ...}
```

First I split the string by doing:

```
array = string.split("@")
# => [a,b,c,d,e,f.....z]
```

Then I got stuck. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to process pairs of elements from the array.

If the array has an even number of elements then calling [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) on the `Enumerator` returned by `each_slice` is enough to get the desired result:

```
string.split('@').each_slice(2).to_h
```

But `to_h` above fails if the last slice has only one item.

A general solution uses [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to make sure the last slice always contains two items (the second being `nil` if needed), to prevent `to_h` fail:

```
string.split('@').each_slice(2).map{|a,b| [a.to_sym, b]}.to_h
```

Comment: This is accurate. That's what I wondering, what if the array has odd number of elements. The last one should point to Nil. Perfect.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Rails question, but in case future readers want a Rails solution: ActiveSupport's `in_groups_of(2)` will by default pad with nil and is a drop-in replacement for `each_slice(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Minor improvement of axiac's answer.

```
string.split("@").each_slice(2).with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v}
```

This does not create temporal arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`result_hash = Hash[*string.split("@")]`

Comment: This is the ideal solution but unfortunately it doesn't work if the number of elements in `array` is an odd number.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have remove `z` from array to make an array with odd elements..

```
> array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y"]
> Hash[ array.each_slice( 2 ).map { |e| e } ]
#=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f", "g"=>"h", "i"=>"j", "k"=>"l", "m"=>"n", "o"=>"p", "q"=>"r", "s"=>"t", "u"=>"v", "w"=>"x", "y"=>nil}
```

Comment: This is the ideal solution but unfortunately it doesn't work if the number of elements in `array` is an odd number.

Comment: updated my answer, thanks for the point me